# How can I programmatically pin an application on a StartMenu in Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, windows-installer

I am doing a major upgrade, therefore, if the user has pinned the application on the StartMenu before the upgrade, the user will lose it after the upgrade.

So I have created a custom action in the installer to programmatically create a shortcut to the application in the Start Menu folder. However, that change does not seem to be reflected on the actual StartMenu. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? Is this only a one way notification (i.e. from the StartMenu to the folder, but not vice versa?)

Many thanks.

Comment: Please accept my apology if this is not going to work. But doing a search around for Windows API items related to the taskbar turned this up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [not possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx) to programmatically pin applications to the Start Menu. This is a design decision Microsoft has made, fueled mainly by programs that kept insisting they wanted front row seats on what ultimately is the user's establishment.

I realize that your purpose here is benevolent since you only intend to do this if the application was already pinned there, but Windows has no way of knowing that.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. that does make a lot of sense. Will put this in the release note then :)

Comment: There is no supported API to do it, but it is technically possible (I've done it out of curiosity).  I would argue against it, though, even for non-nefarious purposes.

Comment: thanks, Luke. I am not going to do it. But I am curious how it can be done. Since creating a shortcut does not seem to be enough, does Windows store it in some deeply buried registry? Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly it was by invoking the shell's "pin" command on the shortcut; I don't remember specific details beyond that.